# Edit values (update state) of List of Objects Flutter

Tags: object, flutter, edit, listviewitem

I'm currently creating a simple grocery list app for myself to use using Flutter. Basically, the user(myself) will have the ability to add grocery items to a list prior to going shopping and as they grab each item, there will be an option to check it off the list and upon tapping the list tile, they will have the ability to edit the price of each item. The total cost is added up and displayed at the bottom. The purpose of this is for budgeting purposes, as I've always had the issue of grabbing too many things and getting surprised when I got to the checkout.

I'm attempting to add the edit functionality and I can't quite wrap my head around how to do it. I've got a list of objects that I A. need to get access to, B. display the selected object on a bottom modal sheet and C. have the ability to update the values before saving the updated item.

I've attempted to write a method which sets the current values equal to the selected object:

```
    final updatedItem = ItemModel(
      amount: _userItems[index].amount,
      groceryItem: _userItems[index].groceryItem,
      isEditing: true,
    );
    setState(() {
      _userItems[index] = updatedItem;
    });
    print(updatedItem);
  }
```

I've gotten access to the selected object but I'm just not too sure where to go from here. Moving forward, I need the bottom modal sheet to open back up and display the values of the selected object and edit those values accordingly. I'm thinking that I'll need to write a separate method which allows to actually update the values? Here's my code:

Shopping list Widget:

```
import 'package:shopping_list_project/components/new_item.dart';
import 'package:shopping_list_project/models/item_model.dart';

class ShoppingListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShoppingListViewState createState() => _ShoppingListViewState();
}

class _ShoppingListViewState extends State<ShoppingListView> {
  static List<ItemModel> _userItems = [];
  static var sum = 0.0;

  //Method to add new item
  void _addNewItem(String item, double itemAmount) {
    final newItem = ItemModel(
      amount: itemAmount,
      groceryItem: item,
    );

    setState(() {
      _userItems.add(newItem);
    });
    _addTotalCost();
  }

  //Initiate bottom modal sheet
  void _startAddNewItem(BuildContext ctx) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: ctx,
      builder: (_) {
        return GestureDetector(
          child: NewItem(_addNewItem),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  // Method to add total
  void _addTotalCost() {
    double tempSum = 0.0;
    for (var i = 0; i < _userItems.length; i++) {
      tempSum += _userItems[i].amount;
    }
    setState(() {
      sum = tempSum;
    });
  }

  void _handleEdit(int index) {
    final updatedItem = ItemModel(
      amount: _userItems[index].amount,
      groceryItem: _userItems[index].groceryItem,
      isEditing: true,
    );
    setState(() {
      _userItems[index] = updatedItem;
    });
    print(updatedItem);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Shopping list'),
      ),
      body: _userItems.length == 0
          ? Center(
              child: Container(
                child: Text(
                  'No items added yet!',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: _buildItemTile(),
                ),
                _buildTotalCard(),
              ],
            ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          _startAddNewItem(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  ListView _buildItemTile() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            _handleEdit(index);
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Checkbox(
                  value: _userItems[index].isSelected,
                  onChanged: (bool val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _userItems[index].isSelected = val;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                title: Center(
                  child: Text(_userItems[index].groceryItem),
                ),
                trailing:
                    Text('\$${_userItems[index].amount.toStringAsFixed(2)}'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      itemCount: _userItems.length,
    );
  }

  Row _buildTotalCard() {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey[300],
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Total',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: Text(
                    '\$${sum.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

New Item Widget:

```
import 'package:shopping_list_project/models/item_model.dart';

class NewItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function addNewItm;

  NewItem(this.addNewItm);

  @override
  _NewItemState createState() => _NewItemState();
}

class _NewItemState extends State<NewItem> {
  TextEditingController itemController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController amtController = TextEditingController();

  void submitData() {
    String enteredItem = itemController.text;
    double enteredAmount = double.tryParse(amtController.text) ?? 0.0;

    if (enteredItem.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    widget.addNewItm(
      enteredItem,
      enteredAmount,
    );

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(35.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: itemController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Item'),
              onSubmitted: (_) => submitData(),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: amtController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
              onSubmitted: (_) => submitData(),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Text('Add item'),
                onPressed: submitData,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Item Model:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ItemModel {
  final String groceryItem;
  final double amount;
  bool isSelected = false;
  bool isEditing = false;

  ItemModel({this.groceryItem, this.amount, this.isSelected = false, this.isEditing});

  String toString() => '''

  groceryItem: $groceryItem,
  amount: $amount,
  isSelected: $isSelected,
  isEditing: $isEditing,

  ''';
}
```

Comment: Did you progress with this? I'm having an issue where I edit the item in the list and without saving the item, the changes reflect in the list when I press back. Have you seen something like that?

Comment: @SmiffyKmc could you post a sample of your code or even potentially create an entirely new post and tag me in it? I'd like to help you out, I just need to see where you're stuck.

Comment: You may want to consider using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com)? You can check this blogs: "[Flutter — Firebase FireStore CRUD Operations Using Provider](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations-using-provider-c242a01f6a10)", "[Flutter and Firestore Database: CRUD example (2021)](https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-firestore-database/)" and "[CRUD operations using Firebase Cloud Firestore and Flutter](https://blog.codemagic.io/integrate-firebase-cloud-firestore-with-flutter-perform-crud/)"

Comment: @SmiffyKmc have you called setState() after updating the List? A rebuild was called after you pressed back which might explain why the changes have been saved after that.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for state management to solve this issue. This helps manage data from anywhere in the app. With this, you should easily display the updated data on your bottom modal sheet. I suggest checking this [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) for more details.